# How to monitor a cassandra table using zabbix

Tags: sql, database, monitoring, cassandra-2.0, zabbix

I have zabbix server 3.2.0 installed in my ubuntu 16.04 server , I want to monitor cassandra's tables and some specific values in tables from zabbix.
I have already installed zabbix agent in cassandra machine, now how can I add item for cassandra's table.

**Example**: suppose I want to monitor following tables values :

```
Select data ,pendintask, transactionid from tablename;
```

After getting response in zabbix server I need to create trigger for some specific values .

Answer (score 0):

If the query returns quickly, the easiest option would probably be a [userparameter](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/items/userparameters). Add a `UserParameter` line in the agent daemon configuration file with a command to execute the query, and you can monitor it from the Zabbix server same as any other item.